# Can This Layout be Achieved Wtih CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have the following layout in mind:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/CjWZgEr.jpg (Stack Overflow won't let me post images...)]

The `<header>` is 1201px (adjusts depending on screensize) ;
The `<nav>` is 100% wide ;
The `<ul>` is also 100% wide (so, the width of the `<nav>`) ;

I want one `<li>` to be always aligned to the left edge of the ul,
two `<li>`s to be in the center, and one `<li>` to always be aligned to the right edge of the `<ul>`. Is this something that’s possible?

Comment: You could put in blank `<li>` items where you have black.

Comment: Of course it is... you'll have to learn more about CSS to do it.

Comment: Yes it can be achieved.. Try `margin, float, display` CSS tags with `ul` and `li`

Comment: Sorry, I should have stated that I’m pretty proficient with CSS and HTML and have been developing for years. I’ve tried all kinds of combos of floats and displays, this is why I asked a question here.

Comment: it is possible if you take a little attention to your html code, see below my answer. just ul + li

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W43Tq/1/)**

If it's possible for you to change a little your markup, yes, you can:

### HTML

```
<div id="nav">
    <div class="left">
        <ul>
            <li class="left">Left</li>
            <li class="right">Center</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <ul>
            <li class="left">Center</li>
            <li class="right">Right</li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#nav {
    width: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#nav > .left {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#nav > .right {
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
}

#nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#nav li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: orange;
}

#nav li.left {
    float: left;
}

#nav li.right {
    float: right;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To be cross-browser complaint, give classes appropriately:

```
<ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li class="SecondChild">Second</li>
    <li class="ThirdChild">Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Then add your class CSS as such:

```
ul {
    font-size:0;
}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:16.66666666666666666666667%;
    font-size:1rem;
}

.SecondChild {
    margin-left:16.66666666666666666666667%;
}

.ThirdChild {
    margin-right:16.66666666666666666666667%;
}
```

Good call @ReneGeuze, no need for additional non-semantic markup.

Comment: no problem! i edited my answer to make the margins / widths a bit more specific, and provided the `font-size` trick for `display:inline-block;` (i personally prefer the no-whitespace between elements trick, but this fit in my CSS code block). if this is what you were looking for, you can thank me with the check mark. :)

Comment: You can also select nth child by using `ul li:first-child+li+li`. Should give you better browser support but I guess it then would be better to just add some useful classes in your html output.

Comment: good point on classes (of which I am a big fan), i'll edit for that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well use text-align justify and relay on behavior of inline-block element:
http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/full/GcBxA

```
ul {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  line-height:0;
  text-align:justify ;
  border:1px solid;
  height:1.65em;
  background:#333;
}
li {
  line-height:1.5em;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid;
  background:yellow;
  width: 10%;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
  vertical-align:top;}
ul:after {
  content:'';
  width:90%;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```
<ul>
  <li>II</li>
  <li>II</li><li>II</li>
  <li>II</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone!

Some great answers here. I needed something a bit more bullet-proof compatibility-wise and a little ‘dumber’ than some of the solutions here.

In the end I went with sizing the `ul` at 100%, and sizing the `li`s like this:

`li.left` - 33.333333334%, `text-align: left`

`li.right` - 33.333333334%, `text-align: right`

`li` - 16.666666667%

Not as conceptually pretty, but fairly bulletproof.